# Incorrect relayouting of recycler view elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing android messenger application and using a **RecyclerView** for showing messages. I have a button that loads all messages from server and scroll down to the last one by clicked on it. However, after clicking on this button I see only half of the last message's content. In addition, when I scroll a little up and click on this button for the second time I don't have a problem and see all content of last message.

Code of setuping the button.

```
private fun setupToLastMessagesButton() {
    binding.toLastMessagesButton.setOnClickListener {
        // Show progress bar while messages is loading
        binding.mainProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        // Tell service's thread to load messages by using handler and post mechanism
        getServiceHandler().post {
            val result = getService().getLastMessages()
            // Tell main thread to update recycler view and scroll down
            mainHandler.post {
                // Finish showing progress bar
                binding.mainProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                // Notify adapter
                getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(result.first, result.second)
                // Scroll to last element
                binding.messagesView.scrollToPosition(getAdapter().itemCount - 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerView .xml code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messagesView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerViewProgressBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[Screenshot shows my problem. You can see that last element have incorrect layout and you can't see a text of message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7L3i.png)

I guess that **RecyclerView** doesn't have time to complete relayouting before calling 'binding.messagesView.scrollToPosition(getAdapter().itemCount - 1)'. I tried to call this function after some delay, but nothing changed. Is there a mechanism to wait a moment when relayoting is completed?

[Screenshot shows behaviour I'm expecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhpoE.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should call `scrollToPosition` in yet another `post`, give a moment for `RecyclerView` for obtaining data and measure/draw (in memory, first frame) new item.

```
binding.messagesView.post {
    binding.messagesView.scrollToPosition(getAdapter().itemCount - 1)
}
```

currently it is scrolling to half of this new item probably because it isn't drawn yet and `RecyclerView` "thinks" that this item is smaller (so scrolling a bit to small amount of pixels, not to the end). I bet your "clear" item/layout (not filled with msg data) doesn't contain this gray area with numbers, so `RecyclerView` scrolls only to always visible username-row

Comment: Yes, I also have same thought. I believe the UI is still rendering when `scrollToPosition` has been called.

Comment: So maybe OP shall scroll after the UI rendering has completed. So is there a listener for him to do so? I know that `recyclerView.setLayoutManager` has a listener which will be triggered when the `recyclerView` layout has been modified, just not sure whether this case is suitable to use it.

Comment: To verify this, OP may add a `timer` or use another `handler` to delay the execution of `scrollToPosition` to see whether this is true

Comment: `binding.messagesView.post` is doing exactly what you described in second comment - will fire after `RecyclerView` gets redrawn. setting `timer` or some delayed `handler` with fixed time amount isn't proper way - you won't ever be shure that drawing operation fit in this gap (older devices may render graphics/GUI significantly slower)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this solution of using `binding.messagesView.post` fixed my problem!

Comment: nice to hear, consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!